# How to find out where a hash reference points in perl?

Tags: perl, hashmap

I have a script that calls a function to go recursively through hashes of hashes by converting them into references, and always adding the next key to the reference. I would like to know if it is possible to find out where a hash reference is pointing. This is not my script, just an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hoh = (
    flintstones => {
        husband   => "fred",
        pal       => "barney",
    },
    jetsons => {
        husband   => "george",
        wife      => "jane",
        "his boy" => "elroy",
    },
    simpsons => {
        husband   => "homer",
        wife      => "marge",
        kid       => "bart",
    },
);

print Dumper \%hoh;

#my hash has way more levels and not all levels have the same depth
#my scrypt does what is in the next 3 lines, just through more levels

my $hoh_ref=\%hoh;
$hoh_ref=$hoh_ref->{flintstones};
$hoh_ref=$hoh_ref->{husband};

#it would be nice to know where a hash reference points, like the following example:
#sub findkeys{???}
#findkeys($hoh_ref);
#should return '$hoh{flintstones}{husband}' the syntax can be different

print "$hoh_ref\n";
print "$hoh{flintstones}{husband}\n";     #same as last line, just to demonstrate what it looks like using keys
```

I know references point to a location in memory, so if the hash reference just points to the location of the data, without storing the keys needed in the original hash, it is not possible. I don't want to loop through the original hash and find where the value is, the point is, if there is an easy way to do it. If not, I can keep track of the keys, where the hash reference is pointing, I was just curious if I could skip that.

Comment: I think madness lies down that path. Keep track of the keys yourself.

Comment: @simbabque yes, I will probably keep track of the keys, I was curious if some perl wizards knew a way to do it

Comment: This is more or less what [`Data::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Find) does, more or less with brute force.

Comment: Re "*I know hashes point to a location in memory*", References point. A hash is a data structures (a type of associative array).

Comment: @ikegami Correct, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: showing more of your real code, including how you are getting the value that you later want to figure out where it exists in the data structure, might help us give you a better answer for your actual underlying problem

Comment: @ysth Well, I doubt it, I can fairly easily track the keys I am using, I was curious if I could skip that part by some sort of trick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *How to find out where a hash reference points in perl?*

`$hoh_ref` isn't a hash reference (or a reference of any kind).

```
my $hoh_ref = \%hoh;
$hoh_ref = $hoh_ref->{flintstones};
$hoh_ref = $hoh_ref->{husband};
```

is identical to

```
my $hoh_ref = "fred";
```

which is to say it creates scalar `$hoh_ref` and sets its value to the string `fred`. In both cases, there is absolutely no association between (misnamed) `$hoh_ref` and `%hoh` except that one of the values of the HoH happens to be equal to the value of `$hoh_ref`.

```
+- %hoh -----------------------+           +- Anon hash ------------------+
|               +-----------+  |     +---->|               +-----------+  |
|  flintstones: | Ref      ----------+     |  husband:     | fred      |  |
|               +-----------+  |           |               +-----------+  |
|  jetsons:     | Ref      ------------+   |  pal:         | barney    |  |
|               +-----------+  |       |   |               +-----------+  |
|  simpsons:    | Ref      --------+   |   +------------------------------+
|               +-----------+  |   |   |
+------------------------------+   |   |   +- Anon hash ------------------+
                                   |   +-->|               +-----------+  |
+- $hoh_ref -------------------+   |       |  husband:     | george    |  |
| fred                         |   |       |               +-----------+  |
+------------------------------+   |       |  wife:        | jane      |  |
                                   |       |               +-----------+  |
                                   |       |  his boy:     | elroy     |  |
                                   |       |               +-----------+  |
                                   |       +------------------------------+
                                   |
                                   |       +- Anon hash ------------------+
                                   +------>|               +-----------+  |
                                           |  husband:     | homer     |  |
                                           |               +-----------+  |
                                           |  wife:        | marge     |  |
                                           |               +-----------+  |
                                           |  kid:         | bart      |  |
                                           |               +-----------+  |
                                           +------------------------------+
```

So, at best, you could iterate through `%hoh` looking for values that are equal to the one of `$hoh_ref`.

> *I don't want to loop through the original hash and find where the value is*

Too bad.

Comment: To get what keys?

Comment: well, only `flintstones`

Comment: `my $key = "flinstones";`

Comment: I am sorry, you don't seem to understand. What I would like to know is if I dont happen to know the keys used in the hash, i only have $ref->\%hash; $ref->{key1}... so on, only having $ref, and for instance, not knowing the hash, can you tell what keys have been used to get that value? I am certain now, that no, you can't. Hope you understand now. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Keys weren't used to get that value. An assignment probably was used, though you didn't show how it got its value.

Comment: Yes, but I assigned a value or whatever the key points to, to it. After that point the key is NOT being stored or used for anything.

Comment: Keys don't point. Keys are string, and it's references that point. And you assigned the value of a hash element

Comment: Yes, now I did, but I could assign anything, I am only interested in the 'steps', and because they are not stored anywhere by default, I need to store them. Fair enough. I will.